# Better idiom for listing inner items of a 1-to-N-to-1 relationship?

Tags: java, guava

I have the following model:

1 RepositoryDTO can have many ResourceDTOs, and in each ResourceDTO is exacly one TeamDTO.

So to get the TeamDTOs from the RepositoryDTO, I am doing the following:

```
RepositoryDTO repoDTO = ...
List<TeamDTO> teamsLinkedToRepo = getTeamsLinkedTo(repoDTO);

private List<TeamDTO> getTeamsLinkedTo(final RepositoryDTO repository) {
    final List<TeamDTO> teamsLinkedToRepository = new ArrayList<TeamDTO>();
    for (final ResourceDTO resourceDTO : repository.getResources()) {
      teamsLinkedToRepository.add(resourceDTO.getTeam());
    }
    return teamsLinkedToRepository;
}
```

I'm just wondering is there a better idiom for doing this, maybe using Google Guava?

Comment: I assume a team can have multiple resources, can't it? Then you should at least use a `Set<TeamDTO>` instead of a `List<TeamDTO>`.

Comment: +1 for properly using final. ;)

Comment: Your code looks good. There is no better way to do it in java.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Keep simple things simple.**

We used Google Guava excessively in one of our projects. And while it was less code and faster to read, it became a nightmare when debugging. So I advice to not use it until you get an huge advantage from it (and simple for-loops won't get any better with it).

With pure Java it's good code. There is no need to improve it.

Answer (score 1):

Good code as Chris states, only one minor change if and only if possible and if the number of teams is potentially large you may wish to consider initialising the new `ArrayList` using new `ArrayList(Integer)`, to avoid the underlying array being rebuilt.  Potentially:

```
  new ArrayList<TeamDTO>(repository.getResources().size());
```